# Invoking pip packages from the CLI?

Tags: linux, installation, pip, spyder

I installed a pip package (Spyder) on Debian using `pip3 install spyder=5.0.5`. However, running `spyder` from the command line interface says that it's not found. I hacked a solution by adding an alias in my `.bashrc` that points to some obscure `start.py` file that launches Spyder.

I'm sure there must be a more orthodox way of invoking Spyder, presumably by editing the `$PATH`, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Start with `pip3 show --files spyder | grep -F /bin/`

Comment: @phd That returns `../../../../../../bin/spyder` regardless of which directory I type that command from. Which is strange. But then what can I do with this anyways?

Comment: Find out where `bin/spyder` is and add it to the `$PATH`

Comment: @phd Is this really how it's done? My understanding is that one should be able to invoke pip packages from the command line interface out of the box. When I look at the docs for spyder, jupyter, or the likes, nowhere do they mention hunting around for bin paths.

Comment: Because all necessary directories are usually already in the `$PATH`. You add it (perhaps `$HOME/.local/bin`) to the `$PATH` once in `~/.bash_profile` (or `zsh` config files) and use it many years after. Nobody writes instructions for an unconfigured systems. After all, nobody writes instructions on how to update `$PATH` to run `python` or `pip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @phd said in the comments, I had to edit my `$PATH` to point to directory where `pip3` installs its packages. Namely, I had to run `export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"` and that fixed the problem.